# Plot issue : bad label ordering with concatenation of strings

Tags: plotting, mathematical-optimization, string-manipulation, legending, scripting

I have an issue about a label which is consisted of a variable name [Omega]BD and a numerical value associated.

Firstly, I put the `BD` subscript to `\[Omega]`. It seems to work.

Secondly, I tried to concatenate all the label with :

```
PlotLabel -> Subscript[\[Omega], BD] <> "=" <> ToString[\[Omega]BD]
```

and insert it like this in `ListLinePlot` :

```
pl = ListLinePlot[{ScaleFactorPast,ScaleFactorFuture},PlotStyle->{Blue,Blue},Frame->True,FrameLabel->{"t","a(t)"},LabelStyle->{FontSize->20,FontFamily->"Helvetica",Black,Bold},PlotRange->All, ImageSize->{600},Epilog->{Style[Text["Now",{0,1.4}],24],PointSize[.02],Point[{0, 1}]}, PlotLabel -> Subscript[\[Omega], BD] <> "=" <> ToString[\[Omega]BD]];
```

But the concatenation is badly done, here is the result :

[image: bad label]

This is not the right order : I would like to print : `omega_BD = 4.9` and not `=4.9 omega_BD`

Where is the error ?

Comment: Try `Row[{Subscript[\[Omega], BD], "=", \[Omega]BD}]` because Subscript is not a string.

Comment: @Kuba . Thanks a lot ! I didn't think that was so simple

Comment: Or use [`StringForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringForm.html), e.g., `PlotLabel -> StringForm["\`\` = \`\`", Subscript[\[Omega], BD], NumberForm[\[Omega]BD, {3, 1}]]`

Comment: @BobHanlon that's a nice one. Why not making it a fully-fledged answer?

Comment: Same question to @Kuba as a matter of fact.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ToString`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToString.html) + [`Subscript`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Subscript.html) + [`StandardForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StandardForm.html)

```
ScaleFactorPast = RandomReal[10, 100];
ScaleFactorFuture = RandomReal[5, 100];

pl = ListLinePlot[{ScaleFactorPast, ScaleFactorFuture}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Blue, Blue}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"t", "a(t)"}, 
  LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 20, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", Black, 
    Bold}, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> {600}, 
  Epilog -> {Style[Text["Now", {0, 1.4}], 24], PointSize[.02], 
    Point[{0, 1}]}, 
  PlotLabel -> 
   ToString[Subscript["ω", "BD"], StandardForm] <> "=" <> 
    ToString[Subscript["4.9ω", "BD"], StandardForm]]
```

> [image: stringsub]